# Layout and sizing issues with TableViewCells that change height based on content inside - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

I'm building a simple messenger app that uses a tableview to display the messages. Each cell contains text and a stretchable background image. When messages are added to the tableview, they do change height to accommodate the text. However, whenever a single-line message is entered, the table view cell appears to be way too long for just a single line of text.

I think it has to do with the initial height and width of the tableviewcell, but I am not sure. How can I fix this to ensure the text bubble image encompasses the text but does not expand too much over it?

Screenshot of single and multi-lined texts:

[image: Screenshot of single and multi-lined texts]

Screenshot of long single-lined text for comparison:

[image: Screenshot of long single-lined text for comparison]

I am using auto layout, if it helps.

ViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    var texts: [String] = ["Hey, how are you?", "Good, you?", "Great!"]
    var user: [Int] = [1, 0, 1]
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: Any) {
        if textBox.text != ""
        {
            let str:String = textBox.text
            let retstr:String = insert(seperator: "\n", afterEveryXChars: 27, intoString: str)
            let rand:UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(2)
            addText(text: String(retstr), user: Int(rand))
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var textBox: UITextView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.texts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if (self.user[indexPath.row]==1)
        {
            let cell:CustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomCell
            cell.myCellLabel.text = self.texts[indexPath.row]
            cell.myCellLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
            cell.myCellLabel.sizeToFit()
            cell.myBackgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "bubbleReversed")?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(60, 50, 60, 50))
            return cell
        }
        else
        {
            let cell:CustomCellOther = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2") as! CustomCellOther
            cell.myCellLabel.text = self.texts[indexPath.row]
            cell.myCellLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
            cell.myCellLabel.sizeToFit()
            cell.myBackgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "bubble")?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(60, 50, 60, 50))
            return cell
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
        tableView.rowHeight = 10.0
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    func addText(text:String, user:Int)
    {
        if (self.texts.count > 20)
        {
            self.texts.remove(at: 0)
            self.user.remove(at: 0)
        }
        self.texts.append(text)
        self.user.append(user)
        tableView.reloadData()
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: self.texts.count-1, section: 0)
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    }

    func insert(seperator: String, afterEveryXChars: Int, intoString: String) -> String {
        var output = ""
        intoString.characters.enumerated().forEach { index, c in
            if index % afterEveryXChars == 0 && index > 0 {
                output += seperator
            }
            output.append(c)
        }
        return output
    }
}
```

My tableviewcell classes just contain a UIImageView and a label.

[image: My main.storyboard and constraints]